# How to return to a new html page in google appscript after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript

I created a google appscript app that includes a form. When submit the form I need to display thank you message. But once after submit the form all the contents get disappeared. How can I do that?

Appscript function:

```
function doPost(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thank you");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the HTML Service as follows.

```
function doPost() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Thank, You!</b>');
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html

Comment: this does not work. can you explain how should be the form tag?

Comment: Dinuka, can you share your code show I can further diagnose the issue?